# Where is input source in ubuntu gnome 15.04

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-gnome, ibus, input-language

I want to set my input source to ibus-unikey(i installed it and set my input to ibus) but can't find it anywhere in setting.

In 14.10 there are a input source tab in Region and Language but now it isn't.

I opened the language section but there is nothing in it.

Is there any way to open ibus please help me.

[image]

Comment: What steps have you performed? Have you used the tool "Input Methods"?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Gnome Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Select *Keyboard and Mouse* and switch *Show all input sources* on.

[image]

Comment: this might be right but i'm already "fix" it. i'm very impatient so i install 15.04 with unity and install gnome 3.16 on it. And guess what it already install ibus-unikey for me.

Answer (score 0):

After having installed ibus-unikey, you probably need to log out and log in again. Then you should find it if you open Region and Language and click the plus (+) character under Input Sources.

Comment: i'm did restart it many time and when i'm open input source it still empty.